# Singular matrix error in python when using dlib facial landmark points for image processing

Tags: python, image, opencv, dlib

I am trying to run an open source python script. I don't have much programming experience and none in python. I was able to solve some problems initially which were related to deprecated code by executing the program at pythonanywhere.com.

The program is open source and you can find the python scripts at [Virtual-Makeup](http://www.github.com/srivatsan-ramesh/Virtual-Makeup). The programs run perfectly with the already provided face landmark points(for lips).

But when I tried facial landmark points from dlib.net as input, in pointpixel.txt, in the lipstick script, 
following errors were thrown.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/JayshankarD/test.py", line 29, in <module>
i_u_l = inter(point_in_x[:up_left_end],point_in_y[:up_left_end])
File "/home/JayshankarD/test.py", line 11, in inter
f2 = interp1d(lx, ly, kind=k1)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py", line 478, in __init__
self._spline = splmake(self.x, self._y, order=order)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py", line 2927, in splmake
coefs = func(xk, yk, order, conds, B)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py", line 2624, in _find_smoothest
p = scipy.linalg.solve(Q, tmp)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/basic.py", line 103, in solve
raise LinAlgError("singular matrix")
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: singular matrix
```

I am using point 49 to 59 for outer lips and point 61 to 67 for inner lips. coordinates of both inner and outer dlib.net facial landmark points for lips I used are

```
207 228
218 225
226 226
235 224
244 226
255 232
245 241
236 247
226 248
217 247
206 243
217 234
226 234
235 234
249 233
235 234
226 236
218 235
```

[This is the image I used for dlib facial landmark points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bihes.jpg)

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: As per the given Github link, The code seems to be very **inflexible** there are a lot of hard coded variables used inside the code, which are as per the given inputs only, So I won't expect that code to get desired results for you, What you can do is take his code as reference and write your own scripts for the same, Maybe that can get you desired results :)

Comment: @ZdaR Thanks for your suggestion. I'll try that.